PySpark withColumn() function doesn't recognize hierarchical structure
I have a task to cast nested struct of struct type to be an array type with struct inside. For this I follow the approach of using withColumn() function. The official documentation says that this function create new column or replace existing one with the same name.
I have this piece of dummy data:
dummy_data = [{
    "return": {
        "a": {
            "b": [
                {
                    "id": 1111,
                    "ts1": "1990-03-11T00:00:00+01:00",
                    "ts2": "1990-03-28T00:00:00+02:00",
                    "c": "C",
                    "d": 112,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "obj": {
                        "obj2": {
                            "id": 111,
                            "col1": True,
                            "col2": 1,
                            "col3": 2,
                            "col4": 4097
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}]

The initial schema:
dummy_schema = StructType([
    StructField("return", StructType([
        StructField("a", StructType([
            StructField("b", ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("id", LongType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("ts1", StringType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("ts2", StringType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("conf", StringType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("d", LongType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("name", StringType(), nullable=True),
                StructField("obj", StructType([
                    StructField("obj2", StructType(StructType([
                        StructField("id", LongType(), nullable=True),
                        StructField("col1", BooleanType(), nullable=True),
                        StructField("col2", LongType(), nullable=True),
                        StructField("col3", LongType(), nullable=True),
                        StructField("col4", LongType(), nullable=True)
                    ])))
                ]))
            ])))
        ]))
    ]))
])

The result of printSchema() function:
root
 |-- return: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ts1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ts2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- conf: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- d: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- obj: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- obj2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col4: long (nullable = true)

I've tried to use withColumn() function:
df = dummy_df.withColumn('return.a.b.obj.obj2', array(col('return.a.b.obj.obj2')))
But, it doesn't recognize the first parameter as hierarchical access to the structure for further casting.
I have this result after performing this function:

I want that the obj2 will be an array type with following schema:
"array<struct<id:long,col1:boolean,col2:long,col3:long,col4:long>>"

with preserving hierarchy.

There might be a cleaner solution, but you can define a function to change obj2 from struct to an array - but we call this function from array column b (the reason I am doing this is because I couldn't figure out how to access fields inside an array field otherwise).
def modify_conf(array_column):
    return F.expr("""
        transform({array_column}, 
        x -> struct(
            x.id, 
            x.ts1, 
            x.ts2, 
            x.conf, 
            x.d, 
            x.name,
            struct(
                array(
                    struct(
                        x.obj.obj2.id as id,
                        x.obj.obj2.col1 as col1,
                        x.obj.obj2.col2 as col2,
                        x.obj.obj2.col3 as col3,
                        x.obj.obj2.col4 as col4
                    )
                ) as obj2
            ) as obj
        ))""".format(array_column=array_column))

Then we can use .withColumn to select all nested fields up to b, combined with the modify_conf to modify the remaining fields:
newDF = sparkDF.withColumn(
    "return",
    F.col("return").withField(
        "a",
        F.col("return.a").withField(
            "b",
            modify_conf("return.a.b")
        )
    )
)

Then newDF has the below schema:
root
 |-- return: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ts1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ts2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- conf: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- d: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- obj: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- obj2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- col4: long (nullable = true)

